# Tuning SQL Server 2008 for web applications

Tags: sql-server-2008, locking, isolation-level, read-committed-snapshot

In one of the Stackoverflow podcasts, I remember Jeff Atwood saying that there was a configuration option in SQL Server 2008 which cuts down on locking, and was kind of an  alternative to using "with (nolock)" in all your queries. Does anybody know how to enable the feature he was talking about, possibly even Jeff himself.  I'm looking at deploying SQL Server 2008, and want to see if using a feature like this would help out my web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff was talking about snapshot isolation

here is the command

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is using READ COMMITTED with the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option set to ON.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this was SQL 2008 specific, it was [SQL 2005](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001166.html).
They did have some DBA help when upgrading, though which you can read Brents's [blog](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/10/sql-2008-upgrade-tuning-for-stackoverflowcom/) entry or [Jeffs](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/adde-a-second-server/)